# How to I ensure few specific apps is always running? If not launch each applications

Tags: auto-start

I am looking for app or a way to ensure specific apps are always running in the background/foreground all the time.

Edit: apps in question does run as a foreground service.

If they are stopped for any reason, they will be started again by the app or process.

Does app called "Tasker" has capability like this?

Comment: Android imposes [background limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) on apps. If an app needs to run in background, it should run a foreground service. See [Why do apps run in background on Android?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/why_android_apps_run_in_background)

Comment: The apps I'm going to run do run as foreground service.

Comment: If the device is for business/corporate use you may want to look into Mobile Device Management (MDM) / Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM), see: https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/ From what I understand you can either run the device in kiosk mode or 'white list' apps from battery optimizations

Answer (score 1):

- Edit application permissions to include background & foreground activity
- Unrestrict data usage
- Exclude from battery optimization
- Exclude from game-mode optimization
- If applicable and/or desired, exclude from Do Not Disturb, etc
- Lock the process (through Recent Apps screen)
- Set up automation to relaunch program in the event of unintended closure (e.g., via Tasker, Macrodroid, etc.)